# Route inside ng-view to another view 404 refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs

flow:

List exists Inside Ng-View as a view called SelectCustomer.html

when a user clicks an A href link on my list inside SelectCustomer.html, route to my other view to be loaded inside the ng-view.

For some reason the route isn't being recognized. Below is the code.

**App.js snippet:**

```
.when('/CcxMain/Shared/CreateNewContact',
    {
        templateUrl: "/App/Shared/Views/CreateNewContact.html",
        controller: "NewContactController"
    })
.otherwise({ template: "this doesnt exist" });
```

**SelectCustomer.Html snippet:**

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3" ng-show="showme">
    <a href="/CcxMain/Shared/CreateNewContact">
        <div class="odd-btn">
            Create New Contact...
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

**LogCase.cshtml snippet :**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="">
        <div ng-view class="view-animation">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the a href is called it displays the default cant find route.  No js errors in browser, any suggestions?

UPDATE: flushed the JS cache and now works...strange. However refreshing causes 404

Comment: Have you configured `$locationProvider.html5Mode()`? Have you configured your server to always serve `index.html`? Otherwise you should prepend `#` (or `#!` or whatever you configured) to the href of the link.

Comment: yes html5mode is configured, seems it was a rather strange cache issue, no idea why but once cleared it works. However i now have the refresh issue that 404s on refresh